# Editing a Sass Mixin from a Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sass, mixins

I'm using Rails and Sass related gems.

When a Sass gem is used in Rails code, it's not easy (or advised) to edit the original @mixin definitions of the Sass gem codebase by digging through the gem files (e.g. "@mixin container" from the Susy gem).

What I'm trying to do is to edit/update/reopen/add-to a @mixin definition **without**:

- going into the guts of the gem and editing the mixin definition
  directly
- forking the repo
- creating my own idiosyncratic 'mysite-container' mixin that @includes or @extends container

I'm finding it hard to redefine/add-to a @mixin without completely erasing the original @mixin defined inside the gem. I just want to add to it, while keeping its name the same.

Does SASS have something like

```
@edit-mixin container {
   /* additional rules */
}
```

Comment: The problem with overwriting the mixin is what, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try do it slightly hack way:

```
%old_container_mixin {
  @include container
}

@mixin container {
  extend %old_container_mixin
  /* additional rules */
}
```

It should work if mixin takes no params, I am now looking for solution for mixins with params.